# Electron Debugging

Tags: debugging, electron, chromium, mac-app-store, redux-offline

I have an Electron app in the Mac AppStore that is essentially just a wrapper around a hosted web app. A few months ago one specific thing has stopped working in this app. I'm using [redux-offline](https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline) to sync changes to the server and this is just not happening any more.

- It's working when running it outside of Electron - in any modern browser.
- All other requests are working fine.
- It's working when debugging it locally.
- It's working when running the built version locally.

BUT it fails in the published Mac App Store version. I'm not catching any errors in my logs (server-side or client-side). I just upgraded to the latest Electron (**electron@4.1.4**, **electron-packager@13.1.1**) hoping it would solve it - to no avail. I don't even know how to properly debug it since it's only failing in the published version.

Any ideas? On *causes*, *solutions* or ways to *debug* it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your application closes by itself. Check all of [app.quit](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appquit) executions. For me issue was that [app.requestSingleInstanceLock()](https://electronjs.org/docs/all#apprequestsingleinstancelock) returns the wrong value for Mac Store build. Please check this [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15958), if the problem is related to `app.requestSingleInstanceLock()`.

Comment: I believe it's not related. I'm basically not using the Electron API at all, as it's just a wrapper around the web interface, so I'm not using the requestSingleInstanceLock or quit.